# Dynamics CRM 4 Activity property validation

Tags: workflow-foundation, dynamics-crm-4, workflow-activity

I'm creating a cusom activity for Dynamics CRM 4 and I'm wondering if there is some way of validating user input. In my case, I have CrmInput property representing a path and I would like to validate the string is not empty and that the path exists. Currently I'm trying with the following code, but nothing happens.

```
[CrmInput("Ruta Fichero")]
        public string RutaFichero{
            get { return (string) GetValue(RutaFicheroProperty); }
            set{
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)){
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("value", "Ruta Fichero no puede estar vacio");
            }
            if (!Directory.Exists(value)){
                throw new ArgumentException("No se encontró la ruta especificada.");
            }
            SetValue(RutaFicheroProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't remember if the decorator `[RequiredArgument]` is valid for a CRM 4.0 custom activity, but will solve the first check (empty value)

Comment: @GuidoPreite Unfortunately, this attribute is supported in .Net 4 and above, and CRM 4 only supports version 3.5. Thanks anyway for your sugestion.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/vstudio/system.activities.requiredargumentattribute(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: sorry, I didn't remember that was introduced only with .NET 4.0

Comment: @GuidoPreite: CRM's workflow is WF3?  Retagged.  If I'm wrong, go ahead and revert.  WF4 is completely different than the workflow released with .NET 3.0.